# How to deal with algebra in Python?

Tags: python, algebra

Apologies if this has been asked before, I’m a little stuck. 
If I had two variables

```
a = 3x+4y
b = 2x+2y
```

How could I make it so that `a+b = 5x+4y`? The way I’ve been currently doing it is with numpy and the imaginary variable. However that doesn’t extend to more than one.

My current one variable code looks like this:

```
from numpy import *

a = 1+3j
b = 2+7j
```

Then I can just you the real and imag functions to get the appropriate coefficients.

Thanks

Comment: _The way I’ve been currently doing it ..._ -> Please [edit] your question and show us your code

Comment: Are you sure you need numpy to run your example code?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Sympy.

```
from sympy import symbols
x = symbols('x')
y = symbols('y')
a = symbols('a')
b = symbols('b')
```

And define your equation using the python variables defined above

```
expr1 = 5*x + 4*y
expr2 = a + b
```

Comment: How would I then get the coefficient infront of the x? Such as in expression one it is five?